# join tables that are on different DB instance inside a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a stored procedure inside sql server 2008 r2, where i use to reference tables from 2 different Database that are defined inside the same sql instance as follow:-

```
[DB1].[dbo].[Technology]


[DB2].[dbo].[SystemInfo]
```

currently we moved the DB2 to be on separate DB instance but at the same database server, so now how i can reference the `[DB2].[dbo].[SystemInfo]` on the new instance ?

Comment: Reference directly like you wrote

Comment: Reference them with a JOIN from the 2 tables

Comment: but i need to specify that the DB2 are on a different schema compared to DB1 which will also have the stored procedure defined inside it ,, so do i need to specify this explicitly something such as [SchameNAme\DB2]

Comment: @johnG I don't understand. You are writing a stored procedure right? So you don't need to define the schema. If the two DB are on the same SQL Instance you are ok

Comment: @Galma88 no the two database are not on the same schame, i moved DB2 to be on a different schema ,, while the DB1 and the SP it self are defined on the defualt schema ..

Comment: @Galma88 apologies , i wrongly wrote my original question,, i meant to say that DB2 has been moved to a different sql instance ... not to a different schame,, so how i can access the new sql instance from the SP ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mooved one database to other instance, then you should add that instance as linked server, call it like `[lnkDB]`, then you can query it like:

```
select * from [lnkDB].[DB2].[dbo].[SystemInfo]
```

Joins will not be different.  You should only add servernane when referring to table from linked server.

Comment: so i will add the link server on DB1 to reference DB2 in my case ? not on DB2? is this correct?

Comment: If your sp is on db1 then you need to add linked server to db2 on db1

Comment: thanks for the reply , but inside my application (Asp.net MVC) i simple modify the connection string from "Data Source=DBServerName" to "Data Source=DBServerName\SqlInstanceName" and i was able to access the tables on the new sql instance.. so not sure why i can not do the same inside the stored procedure ?

Comment: There is no connection strings in database engine. Think of linked server like the connection string.

Answer (score 2):

I try to explain better writing the query.

```
SELECT *
FROM [DB1].[dbo].[Technology] AS T INNER JOIN [Name_of_linked_server].[dbo][SystemInfo] AS S
                          ON T.[KEY] = S.[KEY]
```

If the DB are different Server you need a Linked Server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/ff772782(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: sorry i modified the question,, i mean that DB2 has been moved to a different sql instance not to a new schema ...

Comment: sorry for the inconsistency , but can you adivce on my edit , as i meant sql instance and not sql schema ?

Comment: is there another way of doing this ? if note can you provide some usful links regarding this ?

Comment: @johnG I added a link in my answer! ;)

Comment: so i will create a linked server on my DB1 which contain the SP , then from the SP i reference the DB2 such as [Name_of_linked_server].[dbo][SystemInfo] instead if [DB2].[dbo][SystemInfo]  ? is this correct ? becuase i need to inform our Db admins to create the link server ? but not sure if the link server should be created on DB1 or on DB2?

Comment: @johnG Which is the main DB?

Comment: not sure what do u mean by main ?? now i have DB1 containing the SP , where Db2 has been moved to a new sql instance ..

Comment: @johnG Ok nice. So add the Linked Server in DB1 to DB2

Answer (score 1):

This is simple as you wrote in your question

```
select a.clo1,b.clo2
from [DB1].[dbo].[Technology] a
join [Link_server].[DB2].[dbo].[SystemInfo] b on a.col1=b.col1
where (any condition)
```

But the database user must have access for both of the databases.

Comment: so your code will work even if DB2 are on a different schema compared to DB1 (which also contain the SP )

Comment: database table schema does not matter when You are using join, but please check it first in your case.

Comment: sorry i ment that DB2 has been moved to a different sql instance not to a different schema ..

Comment: ok i got , Please Check this Link (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11832/executing-stored-procedure-that-accesses-another-sql-instance). this can help you.

Comment: the link you provide talks about executing the SP ,, now i do not have a problem in executing the SP since i am using entity framework to call the SP which is already configured to access both instances ,, my question is basically how to access the DB that are inside the new instance from the stored procedure body?

Comment: The above all are right you have to use `link server` here. As your question has changed ,i have also  updated my answer

Comment: thanks for the reply , but inside my application (Asp.net MVC) i simple modify the connection string from "Data Source=DBServerName" to "Data Source=DBServerName\SqlInstanceName" and i was able to access the tables on the new sql instance.. so not sure why i can not do the same inside the stored procedure ?